# Connection per session or multiplexing multiple sessions through one connection

Tags: c++, c, sockets

When designing a client/server architecture, is there any advantage to multiplexing multiple connections from the same process to the remote server (i.e. sharing one connection) vs opening one connection per thread/session in the client (as is typically done when connecting to memcached or database servers.)

I know there's a bit of overhead associated with each connection (e.g. if a server has 50,000 open connections that uses up a lot of RAM) this was one major reason why facebook made a UDP patch for memcached. But I don't expect to have anywhere near that number. Maybe 10,000 at the most. There's also savings in establishing a tcp/ip connection and doing authorization, but for now I'd rather leave authorization to firewall software as memcached does.

Are there any reasons to implement multiplexing connections in a tcp/ip client/server application with less than 10K connections?

**Edit - Details**:

This is for a database server/client I'm working on. I think that Informix and Oracle do actually allow for session multiplexing over one tcp/ip connection. In the Informix documentation they say you may get a performance improvement for nonthreaded clients (no mention of multi-threaded clients, perhaps it's not a thread-safe implementation.)

Comment: Need more details. Do you own both the client and server code (presumably,yes)?  Why would a client process need more than one connection to the server anyway?  Are connections short-lived or do they persist for a long time?  What kind of system are you building anyway?

Comment: @selbie added more details above

Comment: Heh, I was such a noob two years ago about the Linux kernel. Yes it makes a big difference, and the main reason why is because you can process the messages coming in multiplexed on one socket with many fewer system calls than across thousands of sockets. System calls are very expensive, over 30K cycles each if they clobber the L1 cache completely. Context switches have the same cost for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any advantage to multiplexing multiple connections vs opening one connection per thread/session

Yes, though it depends on the implementation of the simplex. You probably know about the firewall hassle with e.g. FTP, SIP et al, especially when encryption is used partway. This is what influences the decision whether to use multiple, or just one connection.